# how to generate rsa key for gdata java api?

Tags: java, rsa, google-data-api

I want to access data feed of my Google Data. I am using gdata private library. How do I generate RSA-Key using Java Keytool ? How do I convert that key to .pk8 format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to generate the RSA key can be found in the Google API documentation:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html#Registered

```
# Generate the RSA keys and certificate
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -subj \
  '/C=US/ST=CA/L=Mountain View/CN=www.example.com' -keyout \
  myrsakey.pem -out /tmp/myrsacert.pem
```

Using Java keytools is very similar.

First, generate the key pair:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myrsakey -keyalg RSA -validity 365 \
 -dname="CN=US, ST=CA/L=Mountain View, CN=www.example.com" \
 -keystore mykeystore.jks
```

Then you can export the certificate:

```
keytool -keystore mykeystore.jks -export -alias myrsakey -rfc -file key.pem
```

AFAIK private keys can not be exported directly via keytool.